# Android download manager saving two file but linked

Tags: android, kotlin, android-download-manager

So, I'm implementing download manager to download pdf files and save it on specific folder. But, what happened is android download manager is download the file, then create a folder, and theres also the same file there and outside of it. But when i delete one of them, lets say John_Pdf on root download folder, the one on partner-wht is also gone.

[image: Root Download Screenshot]

[image: Folder Screenshot]

```
val downloadManager = context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager

for (i in downloadUrl.indices) {
val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(exampleURL))
                .setTitle("Document")
                .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
                    "doc" + File.separator + "document"
                )
                .setMimeType("application/pdf")
                .setDescription("Downloading Report")
                .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
                .setAllowedOverMetered(true)
                .setAllowedOverRoaming(true)

downloadManager.enqueue(request)
```